# I can not create a login to log into accounts

Tags: php

I can't create a login to log into accounts. I created a registration form using the ReadBean library, but I can't log in ... Help please ...
Here is my code

```
                                           <?php
require "db.php";
$data=$_POST;
if (isset($data['do_login'])) {
$errors=array();
$user=R::find('users','login=?',array($data['login']));
if ($user) {        
if(password_verify($data['password'],$user -> password)){
else{
$errors[]="Неверный пароль!";
}
{
}else{
{
$errors[]="Пользователь с таким именем не найден!";
}
if ( ! empty($errors)) {
echo '<div style="color:red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
{

}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylel.css">
<div class="container">
<form action="sign in.php" method="POST">
<h1 style="position:relative;left: 26%; top: -10%;">Login</h1>
<h2><input type="login" name="login" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo 
@$data['login'];?>"></h2>
<h3><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo 
@$data['login'];?>"></h3>   
<h4><button type="submit"  class="RegB" name="do_login">Login</button></h4> 
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is too vague as a description, we have no idea what happens when you run the code - and we have no access to any data so it's harder to predict it. What testing and debugging have you done? Try to give a more precise description of the issue, please

Comment: What does `R::find(...)` do, can you post that function?

Comment: `sign in.php` Is that what your script is named?

Comment: Setting the password value to `$data['login']` is most likely not what you want to do

Comment: I hope your actual code doesn’t look like this, the braces make no sense, please post a formatted version. If you need to redact something, place a comment in that spot.